# On iPhone, how do you back up only contacts not photos without paying for the iCloud subscription?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, contacts

On iPhone, how do you back up only your telephone contacts and not your photos or other stuff without paying for the monthly iCloud subscription?

Comment: Use your free 5GB.

Comment: Or just backup through iTunes using a cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about backing up through iCloud, you can exclude the data of specific apps from a backup; the [Apple Support article “Manage Your iCloud Storage](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204247)” explains this in more detail. I am not entirely sure, but I believe you can also exclude the photo library from this list as well, assuming you are not using iCloud Photo Library. Most apps don’t put that much data in a backup, so you should be able to stay within the limits of the free 5 GB iCloud subscription by excluding the few exceptions.

Another option is to not use iCloud for backup at all, as explained in the [article “How to back up your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch”](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977), you can make a backup on a Mac or Windows PC through iTunes.